# How would I change a targets variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a quick audio player that has multiple instances. When you click to play, the **playing** var is set to true. If one would click on a different instance of **.playAudio**, I'm trying to set the **lastPlayed** instance to false.

I have a portion where I commented out the part I can't figure out.

JQUERY:

```
var lastPlay
var lastSelected
$('.playAudio').each(function(){
    var audio = $(this).find('audio').get(0);
    var playing = false

    $(this).hover(function() {
        if (playing) {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-60px -60px'})
        } else {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0px -60px'})
        }
    },function() {
        if (playing) {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-60px 0'})
        } else {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: ''})
        }
    });

    $(this).click(function(){
        if (playing) {
            playing = false
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0 60px'})
            audio.currentTime = 0
            audio.pause()
        } else {
            if (lastPlay) {
                //** I'm trying to change the lastSelected's "playing" to false
                lastPlay.pause()
            }
            playing = true
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-60px -60px'})
            audio.play()
            lastPlay = audio
            lastSelected = $(this)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: (Nothing to do with your problem): JS is not PHP, variables don't have to start with a `$`. Its kinda uggly ;)

Comment: I totally agree... I just changed it to that because I misunderstood some other solution to my problem. Hah. **fixed**

Comment: @ldiqual: Right, but starting a variable with `$` is often used to stress that this variable contains a jQuery object and not a DOM element. Though this was actually not the case here and therefore even more confusing.

Comment: My thought was by making into a jQuery object, I could then have access to that stored variable and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var lastPlay,
    lastSelected,
    Audios = [];
$('.playAudio').each(function(i){
    var Audio = {};
    Audios[i] = Audio;
    Audio.audio = $(this).find('audio').get(0);
    Audio.playing = false;

    $(this).hover(function() {
        if (Audio.playing) {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-60px -60px'});
        } else {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0px -60px'});
        }
    },function() {
        if (Audio.playing) {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-60px 0'});
        } else {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: ''});
        }
    });

    $(this).click(function(){
        if (Audio.playing) {
            Audio.playing = false;
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0 60px'});
            Audio.audio.currentTime = 0;
            Audio.audio.pause();
        } else {
            if (lastPlay && Audios[lastPlay]) {
                Audios[lastPlay].audio.pause();
                Audios[lastPlay].playing = false;
            }
            Audio.playing = true;
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-60px -60px'});
            Audio.audio.play();
            lastPlay = i;
            lastSelected = $(this);
        }
    });
});
```

I've changed your script in a few ways:

- I'm capturing the first parameter that jQuery passes into `.each` and using it as Unique Identifier between Audio Players
- For each audio player the `<audio>` element, and it's `playing` state are being kept in the local Object `Audio`
- I store a reference to each `Audio` Object as an array element in the global array `Audios`; using the unique identifier as the index
- `lastPlay` now only holds the unique identifier of the last played audio element; I use it to access the appropriate Object in the `Audios` array, and set the relavent `playing` when necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I really appreciate it. I was actually just fiddling around with a quick experiment: http://www.rgbjoy.com/2011 - You helped me out a lot.

Comment: @Tom Happy to help; nifty site =)